# How to write a python program that converts numeric values from a txt file to write them as integers type in an excel file?

Tags: python, openpyxl, txt, anaconda3

The task requires to write a Python program that can read some data about the scores of 6 students of two different exams from a txt file named AI.txt,and write the data of this file into a sheet named "qq" in an Excel file. Code must open the "AI.txt" file first and then convert the current lines into a list. Write the data in the cur list into the "qq" sheet, covert the numeric data into integer type data, and add a column with the average of the data in the first two columns. Finally save this Excel into a file named "AI56.xlsx". I complied with the above requirements, but the data of the two scores columns in the xlsx file is still shown as text type and not integer type. I'm Windows user, using Anaconda's environment coding with PyCharm. (I'm also new to Python)

```
import openpyxl

with open('AI.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()

sheet = workbook.create_sheet(title='qq')

for line in lines:
    
    cur = line.strip().split()

    
    sheet.append([int(val) for val in cur])


for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=2, max_row=sheet.max_row):
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = int(cell.value)

   
    avg_value = sum([cell.value for cell in row]) / len(row)
    sheet.cell(row=row[0].row, column=3, value=avg_value)


workbook.save('AI56.xlsx')
```

[This how the txt file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0jK7.png)
[This is the excel after running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozAC9.png)

My code uses a list comprehension to convert each element val in the cur list to an integer type. But still doesn't seem to work properly. Just the average column is shown as integer type. What is it that I'm missing?

for line in lines:

```
cur = line.strip().split()

sheet.append([int(val) for val in cur])
```

Comment: The code does not match the images supplied (and you can embed the images inline). I suspect that the text file uses a separator so that the conversion doesn't succeed but you can check this easily enough.  You can also calculate the average as you loop.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just use Pandas and keep it clean:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv('AI.txt', sep='\s+', index_col='Name')
data['mean']=  data.mean(axis=1)
data.to_excel('AI56.xlsx',sheet_name='qq')
```

Comment: How could I change this code for the excel sheet to be named ¨qq¨?

Comment: minamiwo if you want to use other libraries, not necessary in this case, you should consult their documentation.

Comment: There is nothing "clean" about this suggestion, it's just handing over the task of casting data types from text file to another library, but the conversion will be the same and the problem probably also not resolved if the assumptions are wrong.

Comment: @minamiwo: sheet_name is the named argument to the to_excel() method of a Pandas dataframe. I added it. Sorry for the oversight of sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries here and there, I made two changes to my code and it finally works, data on the excel file is shown as integers.

```
import openpyxl

with open('AI.txt', 'r') as file:
lines = file.readlines()

workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()

sheet = workbook.create_sheet(index=0,title='qq')

for line in lines:

    cur = line.strip().split()
    sheet.append([int(a) if a.isdigit()==True else a for a in cur])

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=3, max_row=sheet.max_row):
    valores_numericos = [celda.value for celda in row if 
    isinstance(celda.value,(int,float))]
    avg_value = sum(valores_numericos)/len(valores_numericos)
    sheet.cell(row=row[0].row, column=4,value=avg_value)

sheet.cell(row=1, column=4, value="Mean")

workbook.save('AI56.xlsx')
```